# Execute Grunt task during .net core build/publish on Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have a problem with a newly converted ASP .Net Core 3.1 application that only applies to automated builds.

I am:

- Using Libman to manage my client-side libraries as per the
  Microsoft Documentation:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- Using Grunt to bundle sass and javascript libraries as per the
  Microsoft Documentation:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-grunt?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- During my Visual Studio build the client libraries are properly restored via the .Nuget Package provided for this purpose: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1#restore-files-during-build
- Finally during the Visual Studio build grunt properly bundles everything via the Task Runner.

The problem comes in when I'm trying to do the same tasks within a Azure DevOps Build Pipeline or simply from the dotnet command line.  The nutshell is that it seems that the Task Runner is only part of visual studio and sits outside the dotnet command line.  A solution I have found is to add a target to my msproj file:

`<Target Name="MyPreCompileTarget" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Exec Command="grunt default" />
  </Target>`

But this only works if the grunt cli is installed.

Normally I would be trying to use the BundlerAndMinifier library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

But since we are using an ECMAScript 6+ and its not supported by the library I have no choice but to use Grunt or something similar.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?  Should I be following a "BETTER" pattern for bundling and minifying/SASS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you express more on "it seems that the Task Runner is only part of visual studio and sits outside the dotnet command line"? I am little confused on it. Better the error log share?

Comment: What I mean is Visual Studio seems to "magically" run things like grunt if you have a gruntfile.js in the project.  Those tasks appear in the "Task Runner Explorer" window and can be triggered before or after the build based on configuration within the gruntfile.js.    However If i try to build the project from the command line with a simple dotnet build the same actions that are covered in the Task Runner Explorer do not happen.

Comment: In the past build actions were identical whether you were in visual studio, visual studio code or command line aka "dotnet build".  This seems to be a place where the external tooling has to be handled differently depending on which way you are building.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT does that make sense or can I provide more detail?  Thanks!